# Create unique name from Array without duplicates

Tags: java, arrays, string, duplicates, unique

I want to to try to create unique names from an array.

```
public String[] firstname = {"Ben", "Pe", "To", "Jau",...};
```

And here I create a String (Helper.random is just a method to pick a random element). I want to avoid a name like "Benben" or "Pepe"...

```
String name1 = firstname[Helper.random(0, firstname.length)];
String name2 = firstname[Helper.random(0, firstname.length)];

if(name1.equals(name2)) {
    name1 = firstname[Helper.random(0, firstname.length)];
}
```

Now I am stuck. I create some names but then i get duplicates like "Benpe" here and "Benpe" there.

How can i create unique names, like:

> CREATE A STRING name FROM THIS ARRAY IN ALL COMBINATION ("Bento", Benpe", "Bento".....)
>   IF YOU GET A DUPLICATE ("Bento", Bento") ADD ANOTHER ELEMENT TO name ("Bentope")

Comment: What do you do with the names after you create them? Are you using them immediately or do you store them in some way?

Comment: Could you iterate your list to check if there is a duplicate value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick solution is to change the `if` into a loop. You need to keep trying in case you get the same name several times in a row.

```
while (name1.equals(name2)) {
    name1 = firstname[Helper.random(0, firstname.length)];
}
```

Note that neither the `if` nor the `while` ideas match the spec. You're supposed to add a third item to the name, not replace `name1`.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a clause that checks a hash for the currently generated name.  If it exists, then we know that we need to add another name to the existing string.  Check again... wash, rinse, repeat.

eg:
`

```
            String[] names = {"Mike", "Bill", "Jerry", "Frank", "Poul", "Terry"};
            HashMap<String, Integer> nameMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            Random rand = new Random();

            for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                    String myFirstName = names[rand.nextInt(names.length)];
                    String mySecondName = names[rand.nextInt(names.length)];

                    String concatName = myFirstName + " " + mySecondName;
                    if ( ! nameMap.containsKey(concatName) ) {
                            nameMap.put(concatName, 1);
                    } else {
                            // try adding a third name
                            String myThirdName = names[rand.nextInt(names.length)];
                            String newName = concatName + " " + myThirdName;

                            if ( ! nameMap.containsKey(newName) ) {
                                    nameMap.put(newName, 1);
                            } else {
                                    System.out.println(newName  + " already exists in the name map");
                            }
                    }
            }
```

`